# Diferencia entre ./ y ../ en require Node.js

Tags: javascript, nodejs

tengo un require ./../app y no entiendo que significa, ya que por lo que entiendo ./ implica en el directorio actual y ../ un directorio mas arriba, con lo cual no comprendo que quieren decir juntas. Gracias!

Comment: "./../app" es totalmente igual a "../app" Si quiere decir algo es que la persona que lo escribió tenia la misma duda que vos.

Answer (score 2):

Bueno como tu lo has dicho `./` significa directorio actual y `../` subir un directorio.

Utilizar `./../` no tiene ningún sentido porque le estas diciendo que vaya al directorio actual y luego suba uno, cuando directamente puedes hacer `../`

Es decir si yo en mi terminal estoy en `/home/usuario/docs` y ejecuto `cd ./../` el resultado seria  `/home/usuarios/`, que viene hacer lo mismo que hacer un `cd ../`

Espero haberte resuelto la duda!!!

Saludos!!!